# Cherrypy is reachable but not showing anything

Tags: python, cherrypy

I wrote a little cherrypy "HelloWorld" example and the `cp` starts without problem. But I only see an empty page when I do a request to http://domain.com:8888

If I change the port of the request, I get an error of the browser that this resource is not reachable, so I guess the `cp` is generally reachable but not showing anything.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Here is the source of the cp:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import cherrypy as cp

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return ("gurk")

    @cp.expose
    def default(self):
        return "default"

def run_server():
    # Set the configuration of the web server
    cp.config.update({
        'engine.autoreload.on': True,
        'log.screen': True,
        'server.socket_port': 8888,
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'
    })

    # Start the CherryPy WSGI web server
    cp.root = HelloWorld()
    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cp.log("main")
    run_server()
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get `cp.root = HelloWorld()` from? There's no expectation on CherryPy side for value of the attribute so it doesn't make more sense than `cp.blahblah = HelloWorld()`. Your`run_server` should look like:

```
def run_server():
    # Set the configuration of the web server
    cp.config.update({
        'engine.autoreload.on': True,
        'log.screen': True,
        'server.socket_port': 8888,
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'
    })

    # Mount the application to CherryPy tree    
    cp.tree.mount(HelloWorld(), '/')

    # Start the CherryPy WSGI web server
    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()
```

Also your `default` handler doesn't seem to be correct either. It needs at least a variable positional arguments parameter, e.g. `*args`. CherryPy will fill it with path segments, e.g. `('foo', 'bar')` for `/foo/bar`.

```
@cp.expose
def default(self, *args):
    return "default {0}".format(','.join(args))
```